# Run a sudo command with a html button

Tags: php, html, linux, raspberry-pi

For a project with my raspberry I want to host a simple website with a few html buttons that can run sudo commands. I tried this method:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['button']))
    {
         exec('sudo reboot');
    }
?>
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post">
    <p>
        <button name="button">Run</button>
    </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And added www-data to the sudo group and made sure that sudo login requires no password with replacing this line in my sudoers file

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

But no commands are executed, not even non-sudo commands.

Comment: could you try using "/usr/bin/sudo -S reboot"

Comment: Check if there's a `disable_functions` line containing 'exec' in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole lot of reasons this may be failing. I'm not going to provide details of all of them here, but briefly:

- Your application is not just constrained by filesystem permissions. Try [disabling apparmor](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-apparmor-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux).
- The perimissions on your sudoers file may be wrong. It must be owned by root:root and have permission bits 0400
- your PHP code may be running a chroot environment. Check the output of `is_readable('/usr/bin/sudo');`
- Soething else - try `exec('touch /tmp/test1');` then `exec('sudo touch /tmp/testroot');` - see of the files are created and who they are owned by